# Pinch-To-Zoom with Unity 5 UI

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, pinchzoom

I'm trying to re-implement a pinch-to-zoom system in a Unity UI-based app. About six months ago I was able to hack one together by making the UI canvas a child of a regular GameObject, and manipulating that object's transform, but since updating to Unity 5.5+ I find this doesn't work.  The closest I can get allows the pinch gesture to change the canvas' scaleFactor, which a) can make images, panels, etc resize improperly depending on their alignments, and b) won't allow me to pan once zoomed.

What I have so far is this:

```
public class PinchToZoomScaler : MonoBehaviour {

    public Canvas canvas; // The canvas
    public float zoomSpeed = 0.5f;        // The rate of change of the canvas scale factor

    public float _resetDuration = 3.0f;
    float _durationTimer = 0.0f;

    float _startScale = 0.0f;

    void Start() {
        _startScale = canvas.scaleFactor;
    }

    void Update()
    {
            // If there are two touches on the device...
            if (Input.touchCount == 2) {
                // Store both touches.
                Touch touchZero = Input.GetTouch (0);
                Touch touchOne = Input.GetTouch (1);

                // Find the position in the previous frame of each touch.
                Vector2 touchZeroPrevPos = touchZero.position - touchZero.deltaPosition;
                Vector2 touchOnePrevPos = touchOne.position - touchOne.deltaPosition;

                // Find the magnitude of the vector (the distance) between the touches in each frame.
                float prevTouchDeltaMag = (touchZeroPrevPos - touchOnePrevPos).magnitude;
                float touchDeltaMag = (touchZero.position - touchOne.position).magnitude;

                // Find the difference in the distances between each frame.
                float deltaMagnitudeDiff = prevTouchDeltaMag - touchDeltaMag;

                // ... change the canvas size based on the change in distance between the touches.
                canvas.scaleFactor -= deltaMagnitudeDiff * zoomSpeed;

                // Make sure the canvas size never drops below 0.1
                canvas.scaleFactor = Mathf.Max (canvas.scaleFactor, _startScale);
                canvas.scaleFactor = Mathf.Min (canvas.scaleFactor, _startScale * 3.0f);

                _durationTimer = 0.0f;
            } else {
                _durationTimer += Time.deltaTime;

                if (_durationTimer >= _resetDuration) {
                    canvas.scaleFactor = _startScale;
                }
            }
    }
}
```

As I said, this works to a degree, but doesn't give me a nice uniform zooming, not does it allow me to pan the canvas.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Attach this script in canvas object which you want to zoom in and zoom out by pinch

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class ObjectScalling : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler 
{
    private bool _isDragging;
    private float _currentScale;
    public float minScale, maxScale;
    private float _temp = 0;
    private float _scalingRate = 2;

    private void Start() 
    {
        _currentScale = transform.localScale.x;
    }

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData) 
    {
        if (Input.touchCount == 1) 
        {
            _isDragging = true;
        }
    }


    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData) 
    {
        _isDragging = false;
    }


    private void Update() 
    {
        if (_isDragging)
            if (Input.touchCount == 2) 
            {
                transform.localScale = new Vector2(_currentScale, _currentScale);
                float distance = Vector3.Distance(Input.GetTouch(0).position, Input.GetTouch(1).position);
                if (_temp > distance) 
                {
                    if (_currentScale < minScale)
                        return;
                    _currentScale -= (Time.deltaTime) * _scalingRate;
                }

                else if (_temp < distance) 
                {
                    if (_currentScale > maxScale)
                        return;
                    _currentScale += (Time.deltaTime) * _scalingRate;
                }

                _temp = distance;
            }
    }
}
```

**Reminder: This script only works in canvas objects**

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function ( just pass to it negative deltaMagnitudeDiff )
Also it is good to multiplay deltaMagnitudeDiff with a ratio like ( 0.05 )

```
float currentScale = 1f;
void Zoom (float increment)
{
    currentScale += increment;
    if (currentScale >= maxScale)
    {
        currentScale = maxScale;
    }
    else if (currentScale <= minScale)
    {
        currentScale = minScale;
    }
    rectTransform.localScale = new Vector3 (currentScale, currentScale, 1);

    pan.ValidatePosition ();
}
```

For Panning,
you can use something like this :

```
public class Pan : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float Speed;

    Vector3 startDragPosition;

    public void BeginDrag ()
    {
        startDragPosition = Input.mousePosition;
    }

    public void Drag ()
    {
        transform.localPosition += (Input.mousePosition - startDragPosition) * Speed;
        startDragPosition = Input.mousePosition;

        ValidatePosition ();
    }

    public void ValidatePosition ()
    {
        var temp = transform.localPosition;

        var width = ((RectTransform)transform).sizeDelta.x;
        var height = ((RectTransform)transform).sizeDelta.y;

        var MaxX = 0.5f * width * Mathf.Max (0, transform.localScale.x - 1);
        var MaxY = 0.5f * height * Mathf.Max (0, transform.localScale.y - 1);

        var offsetX = transform.localScale.x * width * (((RectTransform)transform).pivot.x - 0.5f);
        var offsetY = transform.localScale.y * width * (((RectTransform)transform).pivot.y - 0.5f);

        if (temp.x < -MaxX + offsetX)
            temp.x = -MaxX + offsetX;
        else if (temp.x > MaxX + offsetX)
            temp.x = MaxX + offsetX;

        if (temp.y < -MaxY + offsetY)
            temp.y = -MaxY + offsetY;
        else if (temp.y > MaxY + offsetY)
            temp.y = MaxY + offsetY;

        transform.localPosition = temp;
}
```

Just call the functions ( BeginDrag & Drag ) from the Events Trigger component.

Answer (score 0):

what i did to scale an object using pinch was this, it works on any touch screen when the object is in the middle of the screen:

```cs
if (Input.touchCount == 2)
        {
            //The distance between the 2 touches is checked and subsequently used to scale the
            //object by moving the 2 fingers further, or closer form eachother.
            Touch touch0 = Input.GetTouch(0);
            Touch touch1 = Input.GetTouch(1);
            if (isScaling)//this will only be done if scaling is true
            {
                float currentTouchDistance = getTouchDistance();
                float deltaTouchDistance = currentTouchDistance - touchDistanceOrigin;
                float scalePercentage = (deltaTouchDistance / 1200f) + 1f;

                Vector3 scaleTemp = transform.localScale;
                scaleTemp.x = scalePercentage * originalScale.x;
                scaleTemp.y = scalePercentage * originalScale.y;
                scaleTemp.z = scalePercentage * originalScale.z;

                //to make the object snap to 100% a check is being done to see if the object scale is close to 100%,
                //if it is the scale will be put back to 100% so it snaps to the normal scale.
                //this is a quality of life feature, so its easy to get the original size of the object.
                if (scaleTemp.x * 100 < 102 && scaleTemp.x * 100 > 98)
                {
                    scaleTemp.x = 1;
                    scaleTemp.y = 1;
                    scaleTemp.z = 1;
                }
                //here we apply the calculation done above to actually make the object bigger/smaller.
                transform.localScale = scaleTemp;


            }
            else
            {
                //if 2 fingers are touching the screen but isScaling is not true we are going to see if
                //the middle of the screen is looking at the object and if it is set isScalinf to true;
                Ray ray;
                RaycastHit hitTouch;
                ray = cam.ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0));
                if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitTouch, 100f))
                {
                    if (hitTouch.transform == transform)
                    {
                        isScaling = true;
                        //make sure that the distance between the fingers on initial contact is used as the original distance
                        touchDistanceOrigin = getTouchDistance();
                        originalScale = transform.localScale;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```